# How to hook multiple times in component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I saw in one lesson that we can create with composition api hook usePromise but the problem that I have simple crud app with to-do list, where I have create, delete, get API calls and I don't understand how I can use this hook for all api in one component. All call works correct but the loading is not, it works only at first call PostService.getAll() and then loader isn't triggered. Thanks for response.

usePromise.js

```
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default function usePromise(fn) {
    const results = ref(null);
    const error = ref(null);
    const loading = ref(false);

    const createPromise = async (...args) => {
        loading.value = true;
        error.value = null;
        results.value = null;

        try {
            results.value = await fn(...args);
        } catch (err) {
            error.value = err;
        } finally {
            loading.value = false;
        }
    };

    return { results, loading, error, createPromise };
}
```

apiClient.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});
```

PostService.js

```
import apiClient from './apiClient';
const urlPath = '/posts';

export default {
    getAll() {
        return apiClient.get(urlPath);
    },

    add(post) {
        return apiClient.post(urlPath, post);
    },

    delete(id) {
        return apiClient.delete(`${urlPath}/${id}`);
    },
};
```

List.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <VLoader v-if="loading" />
        <template v-else>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                        <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger ml-1" @click="deletePost(post.id)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, watch, unref } from 'vue';
import PostService from '@/services/PostService';
import usePromise from '@/use/usePromise';

export default {
    setup() {
        const posts = ref([]);
        const post = ref({
            title: '',
            body: '',
        });

        const {
            results: postsResultRef,
            loading: postsLoadingRef,
            createPromise: getAllPosts,
        } = usePromise(() => PostService.getAll());
        
        getAllPosts(); //get all posts by initialize component

        const {
            results: postDeleteResultRef,
            loading: postDeleteLoadingRef,
            createPromise: deletePost,
        } = usePromise((id) => PostService.delete(id).then((result) => ({ ...result, removedId: id })));

        watch(postsResultRef, (postsResult) => {
            posts.value = postsResult.data;
        });

        watch(postDeleteResultRef, (postDeleteResult) => {
        if (postDeleteResult.status === 200) {
            posts.value = posts.value.filter((item) => item.id != postDeleteResult.removeId);
            // unref(posts).splice(/* remove postDeleteResult.removedId */);
        }
    });

        const loading = computed(() => [postsLoadingRef, postDeleteLoadingRef].map(unref).some(Boolean));

        return { posts, post, loading };
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: The hook is misused. Hooks are supposed to be called when setup is initialized, not inside deletePost, etc.

Comment: but it will be the mess if we call this hooks a few times in setup, when it's in methods I think it's more readable isn't?

Comment: The point is not readability but a correct usage of a hook. It's just incorrect to use it like that, it wasn't designed to be used this way. It uses refs that can be bound in a template and combined with computeds. A promise doesn't benefit from being wrapped with a hook if you still have `createPromise().then(() =>...` everywhere, you could get the same result in `then` without using refs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ref keeps reactive reference to a value that is supposed to exist through the entire component lifecycle. It stays reactive on other places of a component - a template, computed properties, watchers, etc.

Hooks like `usePromise` are supposed to be set up inside `setup` function (hence the name):

```
const { results, loading, createPromise } = usePromise(() => PostService.getAll()
```

For multiple requests, multiple hook results can be composed:

```
const posts = ref([]);

const { results: postsResultRef, loading: postsLoadingRef, createPromise: getAllPosts } = usePromise(() =>
  PostService.getAll()
);

const { results: postDeleteResultRef, loading: postDeleteLoadingRef, createPromise: deletePost } = usePromise(id =>
  PostService.delete(id).then(result => ({...result, removedId: id }))
);

...

watch(postsResultRef, postsResult => {
  posts.value = postsResult.data
});

watch(postDeleteResultRef, postDeleteResult => {
  if (postDeleteResult.status === 200)
    unref(posts).splice(/* remove postDeleteResult.removedId */)
});

...

const loading = computed(() => [postsLoadingRef, postDeleteLoadingRef, ...].map(unref).some(Boolean))
```

`getAllPosts`, etc are supposed to be used as a callback, e.g. in a template, a promise it returns doesn't need to be handled explicitly and chained in general, as its current state is already reflected in hook results. This indicates a potential flaw in the hook, as `createPromise` arguments are unknown at the time when a result is available, this requires to provide a parameter explicitly for delete result.

Comment: I update my question with your answer and after first hook I call getAllPosts(); - is this correct whey to call hook?

Comment: A more suitable place for non-blocking async effect is `onMounted` hook. But yes, it's acceptable to call it in `setup` body like you did too.

Comment: Can you explain please why I can't delete post by id using posts.value = posts.value.filter(...) and what the purpose of using unref(posts) in your code

Comment: `unref` is idiomatic way to get `posts.value` value, and `splice` is more efficient way to filter out an element since Vue supports mutable arrays. You can use those ones you want.

Comment: thanks a lot for help, and I made misprint posts.value.filter((item) => item.id != postDeleteResult.removeId) = removedId - and that's why it doesn't work correctly

Comment: the composition api is really hard after Vue 2 and need more practice )

Comment: When remove every first post it's ok, but when remove another post the postDeleteResult  in watch hook always null, why it's occured?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only the first `loading` ref is returned from `setup()`. The others are hidden and unused inside each method.

One solution is to track the active `loading` ref in `state`, returned from `setup()`:

1. Declare `state.loading`.

   ```js
   export default {
     setup() {
       const state = reactive({
         //...
         loading: null,
       })

       //...
     }
   }
   ```
2. Set `state.loading` to the `loading` ref within each method.

   ```js
   const fetchPosts = () => {
     const { results, loading, createPromise } = usePromise(/*...*/)
     state.loading = loading
     //...
   }

   const deletePost = (id) => {
     const { results, loading, createPromise } = usePromise(/*...*/)
     state.loading = loading;
     //...
   }

   const onSubmit = () => {
     const { results, loading, createPromise } = usePromise(/*...*/)
     state.loading = loading
     //...
   }
   ```
3. Remove the `loading` ref that was originally returned from `setup()`, since we already have `state.loading`, and `toRefs(state)` would expose `loading` to the template already:

   ```js
   export default {
     setup() {
       //...

       //return { toRefs(state), loading }
       //                        ^^^^^^^
       return { toRefs(state) }
     }
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/share-loading-state-hcdwt?file=/src/components/List.vue)

Comment: Multiple loading states will override each other this way.

Comment: @EstusFlask That assumes multiple promises are run simultaneously (e.g., adding a post and deleting a post at the same time). There's nothing in the question that suggests that.